# Array element subtraction index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, subtraction

Im trying to subtract the same element from a different array i.e., [0,0] - [0,0] and [0,1] - [0,1] but I'm just getting an array index out of bounds exception and I can't seem to work out why. Can anyone see a problem with the code?

```
//pixArray and avgPix already contain data
int[][] pixArray = new int[35][10];
int[][] avgPix = new int[35][1];
int[][] correctImg = new int[35][10];

public void correctImage() {
for (int r = 0; r < correctImg.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < correctImg[r].length; c++) {
            correctImg[r][c] = avgPix[r][c] - pixArray[r][c];
            System.out.println(correctImg[r][c]);
        }
}
}
```

I also need to change the loop so that avgPix only loops every time the pixArray column is 0 because avgPix only has 1 column can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Comment: Any reason why `avgPix` is only 35x1 instead of 35x10?  If there is, is there any reason why it is 2D at all?

Comment: avgPix stores the average of each row in pixArray, I just kept it 2D to save myself from getting confused, I don't think it will make a difference I still need to loop avgPix every 10th time

Comment: you say you try to subtract the same element from two different arrays. but avgPix has 1 col, so [0],[0]-[0],[0] is OK, but [0],[1]-[0],[1] is not. This is from your question. bad example maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running r and c based on correctImg's dimension [35][10] and avgPix has dimensions of [35][1]

```
  int[][] avgPix = new int[35][1];
```

The loop in the provided code snippet uses r and c value from the outer/inner for loop, based on what's described in the question it will make sense to use avgPix[r][0] for all pixArray[r][c].

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but something like this will calculate difference with average

```
   correctImg[r][c] = avgPix[r][0] - pixArray[r][c]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i get you, but if you need to execute the `correctImg[r][c] = avgPix[r][c] - pixArray[r][c];` command only when `c=0` then you dont need a loop

```
public void correctImage() {
    for (int r = 0; r < correctImg.length; r++) {
        correctImg[r][0] = avgPix[r][0] - pixArray[r][0];              
    }
}
```

Edit
 after reading your comment on your question, i am still not sure what you are trying to do, (looping avgPix every 10th time?).
 Maybe an `IF` statement is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The second (useless) dimension of the `avgPix` is length 1, but the other arrays that you iterate over of length 10.  This means that when `c > 0`, those data points do not exist in `avgPix`.

In fact, because the second dimension of that array is length 1, it's pretty much useless.  Instead, you should just not worry about a second dimension at all.  To make it obvious:

```
int[][] pixArray = new int[35][10];
int[][] avgPix = new int[35]; //no need for 2D array, since it is an average of row values
int[][] correctImg = new int[35][10];

public void correctImage() {
    for (int r = 0; r < correctImg.length; r++) {
        int rowAverage = avgPix[r]; //this doesn't depend on c

        for (int c = 0; c < correctImg[r].length; c++) {
            correctImg[r][c] = rowAverage- pixArray[r][c]; 
            System.out.println(correctImg[r][c]);
        }
    }
}
```